# The best overload for 'LSTM' does not have a parameter named 'return_sequences' - Neural Network c# with Tensorflow lib

Tags: c#, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to make a neural network to predict how long it will take the water level from point A to reach point B.

I have several types of error on 4 lines of code, and I can't fix them in any way:

```
    var model = new Sequential();
    model.Add(new LSTM(50, return_sequences: true));
    model.Add(new Dense(50, activation: "relu"));
    model.Add(new Dense(1));

    model.Compile(optimizer: new Tensorflow.Keras.Optimizers.Adam(0.001f), loss: "mean_squared_error");
```

I have two errors of the same type on `return_sequences:` and `activation`:

The best overload for 'LSTM' does not have a parameter named 'return_sequences'

The best overload for 'Dense' does not have a parameter named 'activation'

On this line of code:

```
model.Add(new Dense(1));
```

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Tensorflow.Keras.ArgsDefinition.DenseArgs'

And this line of code:

```
model.Compile(optimizer: new Tensorflow.Keras.Optimizers.Adam(0.001f), loss: "mean_squared_error");
```

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Tensorflow.Keras.Optimizers.Adam' to 'Keras.StringOrInstance'

This is all code:

```
using NeuralNetworks.API;
using NeuralNetworks.Services;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tensorflow;
using Tensorflow.Keras;
using Tensorflow.Keras.Layers;
using Keras.Models;

public class Program
{
    RestService_HQ_AHS72450 _restService_HQ_AHS72450;
    RestService_HQ_AHS72460 _restService_HQ_AHS72460;

    public Program()
    {
        _restService_HQ_AHS72450 = new RestService_HQ_AHS72450();
        _restService_HQ_AHS72460 = new RestService_HQ_AHS72460();
    }

    public async Task GetData()
    {
        var result72450 = await _restService_HQ_AHS72450.Get_HQ_AHS72450(Constant_HQ_AHS.EndPoint72450);
        var result72460 = await _restService_HQ_AHS72460.Get_HQ_AHS72460(Constant_HQ_AHS.EndPoint72460);

        // Извлечете първата стойност на item.H за двата резултата
        double station72450_H = result72450.First().H;
        double station72460_H = result72460.First().H;

        // Намерете минималната и максималната стойност на item72450.H
        double station72450_min_value = result72450.Min(item => item.H);
        double station72450_max_value = result72450.Max(item => item.H);

        // Намерете минималната и максималната стойност на item72460.H
        double station72460_min_value = result72460.Min(item => item.H);
        double station72460_max_value = result72460.Max(item => item.H);

        // Нормализирайте данните
        double normalized_station72450_H = (station72450_H - station72450_min_value) / (station72450_max_value - station72450_min_value);
        double normalized_station72460_H = (station72460_H - station72460_min_value) / (station72460_max_value - station72460_min_value);

        // Подгответе данните за обучение на модела
        var input = new double[] { normalized_station72450_H };
        var target = new double[] { normalized_station72460_H };

        // Създайте модел с LSTM архитектура и три вътрешни слоя
        // Създайте модел с LSTM архитектура и три вътрешни слоя
        var model = new Sequential();
        model.Add(new LSTM(50, return_sequences: true));
        model.Add(new Dense(50, activation: "relu"));
        model.Add(new Dense(1));

        model.Compile(optimizer: new Tensorflow.Keras.Optimizers.Adam(0.001f), loss: "mean_squared_error");


        // Обучете модела
        model.Fit(input, target, epochs: 100, verbose: 2);

        // Предскажете времето, когато водния стоеж ще достигне станцията с данни result72460
        var prediction = model.Predict(input);
        double denormalized_prediction = (double)prediction[0, 0] * (station72460_max_value - station72460_min_value) + station72460_min_value;


        // Изведете резултата
        Console.WriteLine("Предсказано време: " + denormalized_prediction);
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        await program.GetData();
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to correct these errors so that I can see any result?

Comment: You need to link to the actual .NET libraries you are using, to me this is not clear.